# @hide class not found

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

The ContentResolver class has a hidden method called [`getSyncStatus(...)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java#2332).

To make it public visible I try to add a wrapper method in [`ContentResolverCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.html) from support v4 lib.

This works so far in Eclipse but when I call `make` it fails with the following errors:

```
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/SyncStatusInfo.java:91: android.content.SyncStatusInfo cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java:19: The import android.accounts cannot be resolved
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java:137: Account cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java:138: android.content.SyncStatusInfo cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java:146: Account cannot be resolved to a type
ERROR: /development/android/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java:148: android.content.SyncStatusInfo cannot be resolved to a type
```

My thought was that [@hide is a documentation thing](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/wikis/JavadocTags.wiki#@hide) only and I can access it from within AOSP classes. But why I can't build my changes when I want to access hidden classes / methods?

**Note:** I don't want to build an Android app, I want to change / build the Android source code itself.

**Edit:** This isn't a duplicate of [@hide class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862346/hide-class-not-found) because @hide means that it is removed from JavaDoc but it is still accessible from Android source code itself.

Comment: IIRC, `@hide` methods are not declared in the *interfaces* you usually deal with, and the implementations are usually not available at compile time, i.e. they're not part of the SDK.

Comment: MikeM. from you link _The @ hide attribute is just part of javadoc(droiddoc also), so the @ hide just simply mean the method/class/field is excluded from the API docs._ This means that it is still accessible from Android source code itself? So why I can't use it?

Comment: @ hide is both for javadoc and for making a `android.jar` located in `<SDK>/platforms/android-*/android.jar`

Comment: Read more at https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Comment: @PankajKumar I think I asked the wrong question :-( I don't want to build an Android app. Instead I want to change the Android source itself to push it to AOSP. At the end I want to change one internal class to access another internal class.

Comment: Can you tell me the classes where you want to make changes and what changes.

Comment: @PankajKumar I want to add a method in `ContentResolverCompat.java`[1] where I want to access `getSyncStatus(...)`[2] in `ContentResolver.java`
[1] ... https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContentResolverCompat.java
[2] ... https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java#2332